# Geoserver imagepyramid and Postgresql for granules

Tags: geoserver, postgresql, image-mosaic, image-pyramids

I'm running [Geoserver](http://geoserver.org/) 2.11.2 on Java 1.8.0_144 32 bits on Amazon Linux together with Tomcat 9. The plugins I have installed are [imagemosaic](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/raster/imagemosaic/index.html), [imagepyramid](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/raster/imagepyramid.html), GeowebCache (internal) and Geofence.

When using the **imagemosaic** plugin I am able to use a Postgresql DB in combination with JNDI connection pooling for storing the granules and time dimension via a datastore.properties file. The file looks like:

```
SPI=org.geotools.data.postgis.PostgisNGJNDIDataStoreFactory
schema=database_schema_name
Loose\ bbox=true
Estimated\ extends=false
validate\ connections=true
Connection\ timeout=10
preparedStatements=true
jndiReferenceName=java:comp/env/jdbc/postgis
```

Which work as expected. However when I add the same file in the **imagepyramid** datastructure, this setup fails. When I add this datastore.properties in just the lowest level (0) then that level gets configured in a database table, while the higher levels are configured using a shapefile. When I add a datastore.properties to all levels, geoserver returns the following error:

```
2017-09-28 07:39:40,780 ERROR [gce.imagemosaic] - 
java.io.IOException
    at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.ImageMosaicConfigHandler.createGranuleCatalogFromDatastore(ImageMosaicConfigHandler.java:406)
    at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.ImageMosaicConfigHandler.createCatalog(ImageMosaicConfigHandler.java:329)
    at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.ImageMosaicConfigHandler.buildCatalog(ImageMosaicConfigHandler.java:962)
    at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.ImageMosaicConfigHandler.indexingPreamble(ImageMosaicConfigHandler.java:941)
    at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.ImageMosaicDirectoryWalker$MosaicDirectoryWalker.<init>(ImageMosaicDirectoryWalker.java:109)
    at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.ImageMosaicDirectoryWalker.run(ImageMosaicDirectoryWalker.java:197)
    at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.Utils.createMosaic(Utils.java:460)
    at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.Utils.checkSource(Utils.java:1336)
    at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.ImageMosaicReader.initReaderFromURL(ImageMosaicReader.java:532)
    at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.ImageMosaicReader.<init>(ImageMosaicReader.java:479)
    at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.ImageMosaicFormat.getReader(ImageMosaicFormat.java:504)
    at org.geotools.gce.imagepyramid.Utils.checkSource(Utils.java:200)
    at org.geotools.gce.imagepyramid.ImagePyramidReader.<init>(ImagePyramidReader.java:177)
    at org.geotools.gce.imagepyramid.ImagePyramidFormat.getReader(ImagePyramidFormat.java:249)
    at org.geotools.gce.imagepyramid.ImagePyramidFormat.getReader(ImagePyramidFormat.java:56)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.getGridCoverageReader(ResourcePool.java:1511)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.getGridCoverageReader(ResourcePool.java:1441)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.CoverageStoreInfoImpl.getGridCoverageReader(CoverageStoreInfoImpl.java:59)
.....
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.ImageMosaicConfigHandler.createGranuleCatalogFromDatastore(ImageMosaicConfigHandler.java:389)
    ... 160 more
```

Is it possible to configure the granules of all levels in the database? And if so, how would my datastore.properties file look like? 
Like I said, it works fine for the lowest level (0) but it fails for all the levels above.

In case this is not possible, will it be sufficient to use the shapefiles as an index for the granules? The geoserver is used in a production environment and I am worried about performance issues when using the shapefiles as index.

Furthermore the imagepyramid automatically names the table after the level folder (0). This folder and table name are automatically created when configuring the datastore. Is there a way to custom name the folder and thus the table name? Otherwise I could end up with multiple '0' tables in the same schema.

Comment: The error seems to imply a typo in the datastore.properties of the higher levels, in particular the SPI configured is not a valid class name. Did you copy/paste it?